# Swift : Changin content of an image from another Container

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, containers

I have two container views as seen in the attached image. I am trying to click a button which is inside the top container which will change the content of the UIImage which is in the bottom container.

[image]

I have a method which handles the change in the class of the bottomviewcontroller:

```
func changeImage() {

    myImage.image = UIImage(named: "02.jpg")

}
```

But I do not know how to execute/call it from the TopViewController.

I have also attached the project : [http://www.koraybirand.co.uk/download/xcode/ContainerImage.zip](http://www.koraybirand.co.uk/download.asp?usr=container&file=/download/xcode/ContainerImage.zip)

Thanks,

Koray Birand

Comment: Use an IBOutlet for your Image and an IBAction for your button. Edit the image using the IBOutlet as a variable through the IBAction func.  IBAction & IBOutlets are created in the storyboard.

Comment: Wraithseekerr, i know what ibaaction and outlets are. But if you read carefully they are in different containers. Button and the image are in two diffferent containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for NSNotification.

Have the top controller handle the button by posting a notification.
Have the bottom controller listen for that notification and make the image change as a result.

(Otherwise, you would need to have the inner controller talk to the container, which would then have to talk to the other inner controller...messy.)

Comment: Thanks, will try it now and let u know.